# What is socket.emit(object, string)?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to understand some server code written in node.js that uses `socket.io` and I found this line

```
socket.emit({ name: 'some_string', id: id }, string);
```

I haven't found anything about what happens when first argument of `emit` is `Object`.

Can someone clarify this to me?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do much. You can listen for those events with `socket.on({}, ...)`, but the use case isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That is for internal usage. You should NOT use `socket.emit(object, ...)` in your code.**

`socket.emit(obj1, obj2)` will send or broadcast a packet to clients like this:

```
socket.packet({
    type: parser.EVENT,
    data: [obj1, obj2] 
});
```

Normally, you can make a real emit with event in `'error', 'connect', 'disconnect' or 'newListener'`

I think this is undocument (?), so read the code for more details
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js